# I would like to store user input to be used in future updates

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have created a batch file to FTP files onto our system and restore into specific libraries. This works well, but it requires user input that I would like to cut down on. If I could store the answers or retrieve them, it would alleviate this issue. Is there a way to do this and how?

fileup.bat

```
@echo off

SET /P name= Please enter in user name:
SET /P userpw= Please enter in user password:
SET /P IPaddr= Please enter in IP address of the AS400:
SET /P TRQ= Please enter in TRQ number:

echo user>> ftpcmd.dat
echo %name%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo %userpw%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd c:\ahc>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd /qsys.lib/ahcpgm.lib>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put PCDIS%TRQ%.savf>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quote rcmd RSTLIB SAVLIB(PCDIS%TRQ%) DEV(*SAVF) SAVF(AHCPGM/PCDIS%TRQ%)>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quote rcmd RSTLIB SAVLIB(PCDIS%TRQ%) DEV(*SAVF) SAVF(AHCPGM/PCDIS%TRQ%) MBROPT(*ALL) ALWOBJDIF(*ALL) RTSLIB(AHCPGM)>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat

ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %IPaddr%


del ftpcmd.dat
```

Comment: Why don't you just hard code them in the batch file then?

Comment: Or just don't delete ftpcmd.dat

Answer (score 0):

This approach requires no user input on subsequent runs once the appropriate values have been entered the first time. 
As SomethingDark suggested, you can just keep your copy of ftpcmd.dat that has the answers written into it.
 You can also put the IP address into ftpcmd.dat instead of supplying it to `ftp` on the command line.
When you run this script, only make ftpcmd.dat if it doesn't already exist. Otherwise, just use the copy that has the answers stored in it from last time.
In the example below I've also rearranged it a bit to put the echo after the redirect which I find makes it easier to read, and I replaced "echo " with "echo." for arcane reasons that you can look up here on SO.

```
@echo off
if EXIST ftpcmd.dat goto :justRunIt

SET /P name= Please enter in user name:
SET /P userpw= Please enter in user password:
SET /P IPaddr= Please enter in IP address of the AS400:
SET /P TRQ= Please enter in TRQ number:

 >ftpcmd.dat echo.open %IPaddr%
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.user
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.%name%
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.%userpw%
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.bin
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.lcd c:\ahc
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.cd /qsys.lib/ahcpgm.lib
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.put PCDIS%TRQ%.savf
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.quote rcmd RSTLIB SAVLIB(PCDIS%TRQ%) DEV(*SAVF) SAVF(AHCPGM/PCDIS%TRQ%)
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.quote rcmd RSTLIB SAVLIB(PCDIS%TRQ%) DEV(*SAVF) SAVF(AHCPGM/PCDIS%TRQ%) MBROPT(*ALL) ALWOBJDIF(*ALL) RTSLIB(AHCPGM)
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.quit

:justRunIt
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat
```

If you really wanted to go overboard, you could check the ERRORLEVEL of the `ftp` command to see if it succeeded or not, and assume that if it failed it was due to bad user input. If it looked like (for example) a bad username was entered, you could delete ftpcmd.dat so that the user would be prompted for input on the next run.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

if "%~1"=="" goto auto
del ftpcmd.dat 2>nul

SET /P name= Please enter in user name:
SET /P userpw= Please enter in user password:
SET /P IPaddr= Please enter in IP address of the AS400:
SET /P TRQ= Please enter in TRQ number:

echo user>> ftpcmd.dat
echo %name%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo %userpw%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd c:\ahc>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd /qsys.lib/ahcpgm.lib>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put PCDIS%TRQ%.savf>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quote rcmd RSTLIB SAVLIB(PCDIS%TRQ%) DEV(*SAVF) SAVF(AHCPGM/PCDIS%TRQ%)>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quote rcmd RSTLIB SAVLIB(PCDIS%TRQ%) DEV(*SAVF) SAVF(AHCPGM/PCDIS%TRQ%) MBROPT(*ALL) ALWOBJDIF(*ALL) RTSLIB(AHCPGM)>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat

:auto    
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %IPaddr%
```

Simply running `fileup` will go to the label `:auto` since the first parameter is empty. The previous `ftpcmd.dat` will be used.

running `fileup x` (where `x` can be virtually anything - its valua isn't actually used) will skip the `goto`, delete `ftpcmd.dat` and operate as your current system does.

The key is to not delete the file `ftpcmd.dat`.

Another way would be to use

```
if exist ftpcmd.dat goto auto
```

If you manually delete `ftpcmd.dat` then the current data-input will be required, if not then the code will skip to `:auto` and the previous values retained in `ftpcmd.dat` will be used.